# How to use regex to select whole string in one match except the forward slash /

Tags: regex

I need some help with regex with this test string:

```
Kershing_User ID/Electronic Delivery_6ZZ138429_ 3142-999999__1
```

I want one match to select everything except the forward slash, so this would be acceptable:

```
Kershing_User IDElectronic Delivery_6ZZ138429_ 3142-999999__1
```

Even better would be to return this with a substitution of a _.

```
Kershing_User ID_Electronic Delivery_6ZZ138429_ 3142-999999__1
```

I know how to do lookarounds and can individually match the part before and after the /, but not all in ***one match***. Anything else I have tried has come up with two separate matches. I am using this with an application called Laserfiche, so as far as I know there is not the ability to do find & replace or to extract a group, just doing it with one match. My regrets if I don't have the terminology correct. I am not even sure if this is possible. I tried for a while and come up with these below, but can't get it in one match.

This does the before: `.*(?=\/)`

This does the after: `(?<=\/).*`

Comment: Use `str = str.replace(/\//g, '_');`

Comment: I suspect your main problem is being fixated on matching the parts of a string that you want to keep. For such problems ask yourself if you could obtain your desired result more easily by removing parts of the string, as suggested by @anubhava. Here you don't need a regex for that, as most languages have a facility for converting a given substring to another string. In Ruby, for example, `"Kershing ID/Elect/ronic_6Z 3142-99__1".sub('/', '_') #=> "Kershing ID_Elect/ronic_6Z 3142-99__1"`. To convert all forward slashes in the string (not just the first) one would use `gsub` rather than `sub`.

Comment: Thanks, but I need a solution that does not use substitution and what I am looking for should be on "one line". It's ok if the solution just takes out the '/', replacement is just a bonus. Seems like it's not possible. Also, I am not coding it using JS, Java, or whatever. Pretend like you're typing it right in regex101 with a test string.

Answer (score 0):

> *Even better would be to return this with a substitution of a _.*

```
import re

a = "Kershing_User ID/Electronic Delivery_6ZZ138429_ 3142-999999__1"

print(re.sub('\/', '_', a))
```

This will replace `/` with `_`. Read more on this [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=sub#re.sub)

Comment: Thanks, but I need a solution that does not use substitution and what I am looking for should be on "one line". It's ok if the solution just takes out the '/', replacement is just a bonus. Seems like it's not possible. Also, I am not coding it, using JS, Java, or whatever. Pretend like you're typing it right in regex101.